# Innerhtml not returning style tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have html content within a div `<div id="divprint">` which looks like.

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<title>05 July 2013</title>
<style type="text/css">.index-departmentheading, .index-gazettetitle { font-weight: bold; font-size: 8pt; margin: 12pt 0px 8pt; }.index-noticetype { font-size: 8pt; margin-top: 6pt; }.index-noticetitle { font-size: 8pt; margin-top: 4pt; }</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/BWCommon.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/SiteCommon.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../templates/ITax_Generic.css">
</head>
<body onload="if(parent.setTools)parent.setTools()"><p class="articleheading" style="text-align:center">05 July 2013</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In my codebehind i retrieve the content with this code :

```
 var tempString = divPrint.InnerHtml;
 var htmlString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tempString);
```

The variable tempstring returns the html but excludes the STYLE tags and its content. Using firefox. Please assist.

I need the string to include the `style` tag.

Comment: **What do you need to do?**

Comment: Divprint is the id of the div that contains the html content

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused too, as I don't see the div with ID "divPrint" that you mention.  Div elements can't contain a full html document (well, it could, but wouldn't make any sense, or even fully work), so I'm confused there as well.  Can you provide more info?

Comment: There is no `div` or `divPrint` in your code.